# GWT and AppEngine User Service

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am using GAE User Service to Authrnicate my GWT Application.
Depending on whether the User is logged in the User is presented with LoginPage/Dashboard.

The GWT Application calls a Auth Servlet  (Window.Location.assign("/googleauth"); causing application to unload which then transfers control to Google Authentication Page, after authentication we are redirected to CallBack servlet.

I can check whether user is loggedin successfully in Callback Servlet. However if I simply redirect back to my application the session login is lost.

The Application loads from scratch.

If I set up a cookie-->

> HttpSession session =
>   request.getSession();
>               String sessionid = session.getId();  //Get sessionID from
>   server's response to your login
>   request
>               Cookie cookie=new Cookie("sid",sessionid);
>               response.addCookie(cookie);
>               response.sendRedirect(AppURL.getApplicationBaseURL());

In my client code check -->

> String sessionID =
>   Cookies.getCookie("sid");
>   if(sessionID!=null) {    //show
>   dashboard }

Is the way I am using secure? How long are the cookies valid for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

```
I simply redirect back to my application the session login is lost.
```

This should not happen. Once you login the session should be there until you logout or session timeouts (you can set this in GAE settings).

You can simply make a GWT-RPC call to server and check if user is logged in: `UserServiceFactory.getUserService().isUserLoggedIn()`.

Note: if you are looking for session cookies, AppEngine uses different cookie names in production and development servers. It uses `ACSID` cookie in production and `dev_appserver_login`.

Comment: Yes, I simply redirect back using response.sendRedirect(""); I make a GWT RPC call and I get false for user logged in. The App Engine settings has Cookie Expiration time 1day set

Comment: Try checking the value of `ACISD` (or `dev_appserver_login`) cookie both on CallBack servlet and your GWT page. 

Also check the path of the ACSID cookie (in the browser).

Comment: Im using a similar setup to yours: I have a GWT page, which forwards to login page when needed. Login page is JSP (OpenID), on selection it forwards to Google login page. When logged in Google redirects back directly to my GWT page. I don't have an intermediate Callback page as you do. Everything works as expected.

Comment: The flow for me precisely is--> myapp then to myapp/googleauth then google services then myapp/callback then i redirect back to myapp. This moment if i check logged in I get false

Comment: I don't have myapp/callback. I set return url directly to myapp.

Comment: Go through login process and in the browser check for ACSID cookie in both myapp/callback and finally in myapp pages. Is the cookie present in both pages?

Comment: i removed the callback and got the redirect to the app straightforward(callback to another servlet was useless). I can see the ACSID cookie in myapp. However I dont get to see the dashboard! :|

Comment: The app dashboard I should see when userservice.isUserLoggedin() returns true

Comment: So `userservice.isUserLoggedin()` returns true? Then you are logged in and login is ok. Dashboard is then another problem.

Comment: You need to check the path of the ACSID cookie in your browser.

Comment: path is "/" what does this imply?